# Why is th:field not working in Spring View

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a HTML web form that creates Sponsored Events (an Model class), I have a Spring Controller, and a Thymeleaf view, and the Entity model. However, I cannot seem to get th:field to work no matter what I try.

I am using this page for reference https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

View

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Create a Sponsored Event</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Create a Sponsored Event</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/event/create/submit}" th:object="${sponsor}" method="post">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/> <!-- This Line -->
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("events")
public class SponsorController {

  private static final String CREATE_PAGE = "events/create";

  @GetMapping("/create")
  public String addSponsorEvent(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("sponsor", new Sponsor());

    return CREATE_PAGE;
  }
}
```

Model

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@Table(name = "sponsor_form")
public class Sponsor {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

}
```

I have tried changing this too

```html
<input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/>
<input type="text" th:field="*{id()}"/>
<input type="text" th:field="*{sponsor.id}"/>
<input type="text" th:field="*{sponsor.id()}"/>
```

And I get the error:

> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "events/create" - line 9, col 26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Model class Sponsors the error is being caused by the @Accessors(fluent = true), I have removed this line and it has fixed the issue.